# ASP.Net MVC project run in another computer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have **ASP.Net MVC** project with local database of **Visual Studio 2013** and I am using this database to my project through **Entity Framework 6.0**. I am interesting when I copy this project's folder from **C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects** to another computer, if local database and it's data will be in this project and if I will able to run this project as in my computer?
**P.S** I am using database first model. After big search I discover that database file is in location **C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT**, so probably problem is that. Project willn't run in other computer because database isn't in the folder

Answer (score 2):

If database type is `*.mdf` - yes, you will.
Default folder for it (if you didn't change it) is `App_Data` folder.
But, make sure that your app has created it.

If you can't find the database, please check "Where’s My Data?" paragraph in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) article.

Comment: I couldn't find any database files in folder

Comment: If you didn't change path to local database, run the project and then check App_Data folder

Comment: It's empty @ivamax9

Comment: did you check it from Visual studio or Explorer? If from Visual Studio try to click "Show all files" in Solution Explorer. If from Explorer - it means you didn't create any databases.

Comment: I check it both and both of them is empty

Comment: Of course I create because it works on my computer, but I don't think this database exists in this folder

Comment: I am not using code first. First I create database @ivamax9

Comment: <connectionStrings><add name="DVL_New_WorkingWithSQLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.DVL_New_WorkingWithSQLModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.DVL_New_WorkingWithSQLModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.DVL_New_WorkingWithSQLModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\Projects;initial catalog=DVL_New_WorkingWithSQL;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>

Comment: so yes, you have override path, so check this place %USERPROFILE%\Projects via windows explorer, so after copy, you need to place it in the same folder you can change path to it

Answer (score 2):

As long as the other machine have installed at least the same version of VS then you will be able to run the application without problems. Anyway, if you have any problem with the database you always can run the scripts again and the `Seed` method that will insert your default values.

Comment: On another machine is Visual Studio 2012 and project cann't connect to database

Comment: Many can be your problems. Please read this tutorial to build again your db https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: Dont forget to mark as answers. This is how SO works :)

Comment: Yes I will :).  But first it might work for my question and then I will mark :)

Comment: Your link is for code first model. I am using database first model and i think this is the problem. I can generate database from model,but in this case my database data will lost

Comment: What you can do is insert the sample data you need on Seed method

Comment: Ok. Thank you. If it will help, I will mark answer :))

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes used Seed method http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx